# PostgreSQL: Why calling function (NUMERIC -> NUMERIC) in SELECT is too expensive?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query with a long select part with many cases when statement and I tried to put them to function for clarity, but the query start running longer than before.

So, for testing, I create one simple table

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
select random()::numeric from generate_series(1, 5000000, 1)
```

and one very simple function

```
create funtion f1 (i NUMERIC)
returns NUMERIC
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$
begin
return i+1
end
$body$
```

and running two queries:

```
1: SELECT random, random+1 from T1
2: SELECT random, f1(random) from T1
```

and I don't know why the first is running two times faster than the second, so please help.
Sorry for my English :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the function `f1` has to be called for every row, and calling a PL/pgSQL function is quite expensive.

If you define it as an SQL function, it could be inlined, which would be much cheaper:

```
FREATE FUNCTION f1(i NUMERIC) RETURNS numeric
   LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT i + 1';
```

Comment: Will `volatile` functions be inlined? I thought you'd need to define it as `immutable` or `stable`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `VOLATLE` functions are more likely to be inlined than `IMMUTABLE` ones.